# Python doesn't return correct values with a dictionary using a function

Tags: python, list, function, dictionary, return

I have a function that returns an array of values and another array with dictionaries, All dictionaries are different but it returns the same value

When I print it form the function I get correct values for example

```
{0: 0}
{0: 1, 1: 0}
{0: 2, 1: 1, 2: 0}      
{0: 3, 1: 5, 2: 0}      
{0: 4, 1: 1, 2: 0}      
{0: 5, 1: 0, 2: 0}      
{0: 6, 1: 5, 2: 0}      
{0: 7, 1: 2, 2: 1, 3: 0}
```

But when I return the array y get this (the wrong answer)

```
([0, 2, 4, 4, 6, 1, 6, 5], # This array is correct
 [{0: 7, 1: 2, 2: 1, 3: 0}, # From here is incorrect
  {0: 7, 1: 2, 2: 1, 3: 0},
  {0: 7, 1: 2, 2: 1, 3: 0},
  {0: 7, 1: 2, 2: 1, 3: 0},
  {0: 7, 1: 2, 2: 1, 3: 0},
  {0: 7, 1: 2, 2: 1, 3: 0},
  {0: 7, 1: 2, 2: 1, 3: 0},
  {0: 7, 1: 2, 2: 1, 3: 0}])
```

This is the fragment of code with this problem

```
    .
    .
    .
    for i in range(n):
        j = i
        count = 0
        while parent[j] != -1:
            s[i][count] = j
            count = count + 1
            j = parent[j]
        s[i][count] = start
        ###########
        print(s[i])
        ###########
        
    return dist, s
```

Comment: "This is the fragment of code with this problem" No, you *must always provide a [mcve]*. Please see the [help] and [ask]. In any case, almost *certainly* the problem is that you are putting the same `dict` in the list multiple times.  Without a [mcve] we can only speculate. You *claim* that all the `dict` objects are different, but your debugging print *strongly suggests you are mistaken*. How are you verifying that they are different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what u 're looking for:

```
for i in range(n):
        j = i
        s = []
        while parent[j] != -1:
            s.append(j)
            j = parent[j]
        s.append(start)
        path[i] = s[::-1]
```